# Pros and cons of using perspectives?

Tags: style, perspective

What are the pros and cons of using first person/second person/third person perspective in your story?

Comment: Duplicate but I can't find the link on my phone.

Comment: As @StrixVaria mentions, the following questions/answers are related: http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/2/16, http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/273/16

Comment: I also think this is a little too broad. This Q would be better if it were a specific question about a specific voice.

Comment: can you differentiate this more from [the question StrixVaria mentioned](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/2/16)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few main points are:

First person - you (the reader) have a closer relationship with the character. You are more likely to feel what they feel. (I guess :P)

Second person - you are in the story, used commonly in the "pick your path" stories because it is YOU in the sticky situation, so YOU must pick the path.

Third person - Gives a larger view of what is happening in the world. You can find out things about multiple characters because you are not restricted to the eyes of a character.